# Mirror across 4 dimensional plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Given is the following plane in $R^4:$

[image]

I need to find the mirror across the plane. Hint: first find a normal vector to the plane.

The fact that it is in 4 dimensions disturbs me a bit. To find a normal vector, I can’t just use the cross product. Also, I don’t realy see how I can find the mirror using the normal vector. Thanks for your help.

(Btw: this is not homework. Our professor gave us old exams, but no solutions to them. That doesn’t realy help me.)

Edit: here are the 3 vectors of the plane if you can't see the picture

\begin{align}
    y &= \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           2 \\
           0 \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

\begin{align}
    y &= \begin{bmatrix}
           -1 \\
           1 \\
           3 \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

\begin{align}
    y &= \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           0\\
           0 \\
           1
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

Comment: I can't see the picture.

Comment: How is that possible ??

Comment: The vectors are 1;2;0;0 , 0;0;0;1, and -1;1;3;0 I will try to do it in latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a normal vector $\vec n$,  first find an equation of the plane, it will have the form $ \vec n \cdot \vec v =0$. Then use the normal vector together with a basis of the plane to form an appropriate basis of $R^4 $.

Another method to find the normal vector,  solve a system of $3 $ equations made of  dot products that must be $0 $.

Comment: Is there no easier way to find a normal vector ? And when I found it, I don't really see how I can use it to make a mirror. For the basis of the plane, I could take whatever basis, is that right ? And then, what should I do ?

Comment: The vectors you have have a lot of zeroes so the system is really easy to solve.

Comment: For the second part, just think of what you would do in 3 dimensions. Or even two.

Comment: Okay, i found a normal vector. Fairly easy, that's right. I found 2;-1;1;0 But now, I'm still a bit troubled. For reflecting, I would try to "invert" all coordinates except those of the plane. But I don't see how to do it.

Comment: For the basis, I could take the vector of the plane as they are, is that right ?

Comment: Absolutely.  Now the mirror of  $\vec v +a\vec n $ is $ \vec v-a\vec n $.

Comment: Okay, first, thanks a lot for your help ! Now, just to be sure, the reflection can be written as a combination of the vectors of the basis of the plane (which can simply be given by the vectors of the plane) minus something time the normal vector that we found. So I just have to write basis of the plane minus some number times normal vector, and that is the reflection. Is that right ?

Comment: It depends on what the problem is really asking,  it could be the matrix of the reflection in the usual basis.

Comment: The problem was asking "Calculate the reflection $A:R^4 $to $R^4$ according to the plane"

Comment: So yes I think the question is to find the matrix.